# 404 on IIS although dynamic content is active

Tags: iis, angular

I wrote an Angular2 app in VSCode and startet it with `lite-server` routing and refreshing works perfectly and without any problems. But when I'm trying to deploy the app on a `Windows Server 2012 R2 in IIS 8` I got 404 error messages on nearly everything I installed in my `node_modules` folder. 
At this time my base href was looking like this `<base href="/">`.

So after a while of searching a way to fix it I found something to change base href to `<base href="@Url.Content("~/")" />` and with that my page is working and even my routing works fine. But when I'm trying to refresh the browser page the page is showing 404 Error.

That seemed to be a problem of dynamic content of IIS. So I activated dynamic content but its still showing 404 after page refreshing. 
So I tryed something like this

```
bootstrap(AppComponent, [
    ROUTER_PROVIDERS,
    provide(APP_BASE_HREF, useValue: '/#/'),
    provide(LocationStrategy, useClass: HashLocationStrategy)
]);
```

Page is working with that on lite-server( routing refreshing etc.) but on IIS still getting 404 Error on refreshing.
I read something about rewriting url with web.config but I can't get anything to work.

It's my first angular2 page to deploy so please be patient wit me.

I hope some of you can help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A combination of Günter's and AngJobs answer did it for me.

I solved it with [Url Rewriter](http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite)

and with the given code

```
bootstrap(AppComponent, [
ROUTER_PROVIDERS,
provide(APP_BASE_HREF, {useValue: '/'}),
provide(LocationStrategy, {useClass: HashLocationStrategy})
]);
```

I created a UrlRewriter rule like that:
[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wKXKW.png)

And with that my page is working perfect. Routing is still working and on page refresh the Url is rewritten and no Errors occure.

Thx for your both help that leed me to solve it!

Marv

Answer (score 2):

You should configure IIS or via web.config to always return the Index/Default page (for any route)

Comment: Here's a sample web.config that does exactly that: http://jasonwatmore.com/post/2016/07/26/AngularJS-enable-html5mode-page-refresh-without-404-error-in-NodeJS-and-IIS.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I think it should be

```
bootstrap(AppComponent, [
    ROUTER_PROVIDERS,
    provide(APP_BASE_HREF, {useValue: '/'}),
    provide(LocationStrategy, {useClass: HashLocationStrategy})
]);
```

Comment: with that my url is switching from "server/app/dashboard" to "server/dashboard" and on refresh i still got a 404 because its trying to get the "dashboard" folder. Maybe there should be a rewriting to app/dashboard? nut i don't know how

Comment: You could try to change `useValue: '/app/dashboard/` or `/server/app/dashboard/`. I don't know your setup.

Answer (score 0):

The following PowerShell code will fix this issue.  Based on the official Angular 2 docs (http://blog.angular-university.io/angular2-router/) the "solution" is to forward back to your index.html which will then account for the routes:

```
Import-WebAdministration
# Grab the 404 handler and update it to redirect to index.html.
$redirect = Get-WebConfiguration -filter "/system.WebServer/httperrors/error[@statusCode='404']" -PSPath IIS:\Sites\LIS 
$redirect.path = "/index.html"
$redirect.responseMode = 1
# shove the updated config back into IIS
Set-WebConfiguration -filter "/system.WebServer/httperrors/error[@statusCode='404']" -PSPath IIS:\Sites\LIS -value $redirect
```

Comment: at the moment i`m upgrading my application from beta to realease, after that i will look at your solution.
please be patient with me :)